# What is the meaning of Refactor --> Extract function in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring

I have used refactor for copying, moving and renaming but I want to expand my horizon for feature use so I wanted to know what Extract feature does and how it helps to increase productivity and code cleanliness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Extract Method" can help you reduce the size of your methods. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello!");
    System.out.println("My name is Sweeper!");
    System.out.println("I write code in Java.");
}
```

If I select the three lines of `System.out.println`, and do "Extract Method", and give it a name of `selfIntro`, I get the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    selfIntro();
}

private static void selfIntro() {
    System.out.println("Hello!");
    System.out.println("My name is Sweeper!");
    System.out.println("I write code in Java.");
}
```

Comment: and what about delegates interface variable?? does the same concept applies for others too??

Comment: @AkashPal why not try them yourself?

Comment: well yeah i would now its just that i am new to the android studio and didn't wanna mess things up now, that i know the underlying functionality

Comment: @AkashPal It won't mess anything up if you do it in a brand new project. "Extract Delegate" will create a new class and move your selected methods to that class. "Extract Interface" will create an interface with your selected methods, and make the surrounding class implement the interface. "Extract Variable" will declare a variable initialised to the value of your selected expression and replace your selected expression with that variable. See the pattern?

Comment: oh great thanks for explanation . i have selected your answer as accepted answer